# rewrite PHP code into Python (POST request)

Tags: php, python, json, post

I need to rewrite this small piece of code in Python.

The code makes a POST request to the specified URL. In this request you must pass along your API key. All responses will be in the JSON format.

```
<?php

$url = 'https://probasketballapi.com/teams';

$api_key = '__YOUR__API__KEY__';

$query_string = 'api_key=' . $api_key . '&team_abbrv=BOS';

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $query_string);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

$result = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);

echo $result;

?>
```

this is the code i have currently, the response is saying invalid api key but i know its correct

```
import urllib, urllib2, json, requests

url_1='http://api.probasketballapi.com/team'
api_key='fakeAPIkey'

query_string = 'api_key='+ api_key + '&team_abbrv=BOS'
query_string2={'query_string': query_string}

r = requests.post(url_1, data=query_string2)
```

when i print r.text i get "u'Invalid API key.'"

Comment: "**I** need to rewrite this small piece of code in Python." So what have you got so far?

Comment: why you convert query string into json string ? json string is not correct POST data.

Comment: @furas im not sure i was following sample code online

Comment: @DavidVilla I think YashMehrotra answer is correct.

Answer (score 1):

One way to try this would be

```
query = {'api_key': 'my_api_key', 'team_abbrv': 'BOS'}
r = requests.post(url_1, data=query)
```

Answer (score 0):

From wikipedia:

A typical URL containing a query string is as follows:

http://example.com/over/there?name=ferret

I think you just forgot the first `?`

so your url should be formatted as 
`query_string = '?api_key='+ api_key + '&team_abbrv=BOS'`

where the first query parameter is preceded by the question mark